# I am getting 'uncompression error system halted' when I try to boot from my new ssd

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation

I did a fresh install of ubuntu 18.04 lts on SSD but I get this error on my first boot and after two tries I get '452:out of range pointer: 0xe115837b aborted press any key to exit..' 
I don't have any other os installed or any other HDD.
I am using t430,4gb,256ssd.
Ps- I haven't created a swap area

How can I solve this?
Is this a hardware issue?

Comment: Who manufactured the SSD?

Comment: Western digital